# Build failed - unable to find SDK path in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

Good day, I have the path set up in Unity 5.5.0f3 Personal,and I know that the path is correct, but when I build for android after switching platforms, I get the following message :

> Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct.

I tried to reset the path again and have it set in my environment variables, but still no luck.

[image: Image of error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because Unity is unable to detect targets platform try to open SDK manager and redownload your minimum API and the target API.